# How can I set some data from a received response witch format is TEXT in postman

Tags: postman, textformat

I want to set some data in the environment from a received response witch format is TEXT in postman. any idea of doing this. thanks a lot, for example, the highlighted phone number. tried to change response type to JSON but that makes things even worse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cheerio` to parse the HTML response received in the `Tests` script and pick any data you want from the parsed HTML.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text())

...
```

- Cheerio: https://cheerio.js.org/
- Postman Scripts: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox/